# How do you disallow DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute from being placed on the code generated by the dataset designer?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, strongly-typed-dataset

I would like to step through dataset designer code in an ASP.NET project. How can I ensure that this:

```cs
[global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
```

is not included on the code it generates?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot prevent this from happening.  However, you can enable stepping through properties, methods that are tagged with this attribute by disabling Just My Code.

Go to Tools -> Option and select the Debugger node.  One the right there should be a check box with the text containing "Enable Just My Code".  Uncheck that box and you will be able to step into your dataset code.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a mysterious DataSet problem by simply editing the .Designer.cs file and commenting out the appropriate DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute declarations.  If you want to take it further, you could automate this by adding a pre-build event that removes all of these lines using something like [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm).

Here's the command you need:

```
C:\PathToSed\sed.exe -i "s/.*DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute.*//g" $(ProjectDir)MyDataSet.Designer.cs
```